# How to enforce a 1:M relation in a M:M?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, entity-framework-core, database-schema

I am designing a database schema.

There are presently 2 tables:

1. Task (TaskID, TaskName)
2. Description (DescriptionID, Description)

A task can have multiple descriptions, but the same description shouldn't be shared by multiple tasks. A description can have 0 or 1 task (User should be able to add description without task and be able to link a task later).

**Option 1:**

Add TaskID as nullable foreign key in the Description table.

**Option 2**

Instead, I can create another table called TaskDescription(RowID, TaskID, DescriptionID). *But it is now a M:M. A task can have multiple descriptions, and a description can be shared by multiple tasks. In this case, how to prevent more than 1 task from sharing the same description?*

Comment: In option 2 you can create a description independent of a task, even if the task does not exist. Does this make sense?
Use OPT 1 all columns NOT NULL this makes description optional. Also do not forget UNIQUE on Description_Text.

Comment: Option 1 also allows to create description independent of task by making foreign key nullable.

Comment: Hello are you there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Option 2

> Instead, I can create another table called TaskDescription(RowID, TaskID, DescriptionID). But it is now a M:M. A task can have multiple descriptions, and a description can be shared by multiple tasks. In this case, how to prevent more than 1 task from sharing the same description?

Only two columns with a composite primary key (on both columns, obviously) would suffice for *another table*, along with **unique index** on `descriptionID` which will enforce

> but the same description shouldn't be shared by multiple tasks

Something like this (Oracle syntax; disregard that. I hope it is easier to see what I mean by looking at some code, rather than reading my non-native English speaking description):

```
create table taskDescription
  (taskID         number  constraint fk_td_task references task (task_id),
   descriptionID  number  constriant fk_td_desc references description (descriptionID),
  --
  constraint pk_td primary key (taskID, descriptionID)
  );

create unique index ui1_td on taskDescription (descriptionID);
```

Doing so, database will handle everything and raise an error if you try to violate any of enforced constraints.